# Star rating raty - how to save to database

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to wrap my head around the functionality of this star rating  with JQuery Raty Plugin.
I basically have a table called review which has 5 columns rtg1-5, since I need to ate 5 different aspects in one review.

In the new review form, I added this to test if it works for saving values in the first of them

```
 <%= form_for ([@review.fcomp, @review])  do |f| %>
 .....lots of other fields
<div class="form-group row">
<%= f.label 'Luggage handling', class: 'col-sm-4 form-control-label' %>
<div class="col-sm-6" id='star-rating'></div>
</div>
```

And added this at the bottom of the form

```
<script>
$('#star-rating').raty({
path: '/assets',
scoreName: 'review.rtg1'
});
</script>
```

I do not understand exactly how in all this star-rating script I can pass and tell the database to update the column rtg1 in the table review with the number of selected stars?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: You need to submit the data via jquery ajax $.post method to your server.

Comment: If you're stuck, there's a great walkthrough for rails and Raty here: https://www.rubyplus.com/articles/4011-Using-Star-Rating-jQuery-Plugin-Raty-with-Twitter-Bootstrap-4-in-Rails-5-Apps

Comment: Thanks. It was exactly what I started googling for after I asked the question. Guess I have to brush up on the ajax and see if I figure out how that's done.
That link was exactly the one I used to come this far. But it doesn't explain the ajax part. unless I am missing something.

May I ask if in case I would end up with 5 different ratings in my page, is Ajax still the right call? I only want data written to the DB when the submit button is pressed, and not when the stars are pressed

Comment: If you only want to update your db on form submit you don't need ajax.  In that case, let the plugin handle highlighting stars visually only and then just submit the new rating with the rest of the form.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers,  @bkunzi01
But I do not understand how I can have this part of the form connected to my :rtg1 field...

Comment: Just add an f.input :rtg1   field to your form.

Comment: In the link you provided, they replace 

     <%= f.number_field :rating %>

with 

     <div class="col-sm-6" id='star-rating'></div>

And then in the script it seems to tell where to place that values

      scoreName: 'review[rating]'


My problem is that I do not have a sepparate model called review. My review is already a table where I added these columns. But simply replacing with 

     scoreName: 'review.rtg1' 
didn't lead anywhere

Comment: Thanks for the f.input suggestion. But I still don't understand how is the script connecting the selected number of stars to a value for that field. 
I probably have to use hiddden_field for it
     <%= f.hidden_field :rtg1 %>

Comment: You need to assign the id ('star-rating') to your form field so your script at the bottom knows they're linked.  f.input :rtg1, input_html: { id: 'star-rating' }   You may want to use simpleform for this since it makes adding and styling forms amazingly simple.

Comment: You won't need 5 columns but just one, bkunzi01 points to a great tutorial

Comment: @s1mpl3 - I started with one column but it didn't make much sense in the way I wanted the reviews summarized afterwards. Or maybe I'm not not used with simplifying the model I have in my head to only use one column...
The tutorial was very useful up to the point I had to ask this question. Trying to figure out the last suggestion from bkunzi01 now

Answer (score 0):

With the hidden field you added change your raty config to

```
scoreName: 'review[rtg1]'
```

or whatever ends up being the value of the hidden field's name